# Why am I getting a an 'instance method not found' message here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, warnings

I'm currently using the `MKHorizMenu` class found [here](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKHorizMenuDemo/tree/master/MKHorizMenu) and I'm trying to understand why I am getting an instance method not found message.

I'm trying to have the app programatically do the equivalent of tapping on of the items on the view controllers first load.

**My code:**

```
// Actually select the item
[self.horizMenu.itemSelectedDelegate horizMenu:self.horizMenu itemSelectedAtIndex:0];

// Tap the button (change its background image etc)
NSArray *subs = [self.horizMenu subviews];
[self.horizMenu buttonTapped:(id)[subs objectAtIndex:0]]; // guilty line
```

**The warning:**

`warning: instance method '-buttonTapped:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

In the `MKHorizMenu` class the method is defined as:

`-(void) buttonTapped:(id) sender`

When I run the code, it performs as desired - it appears as if the first button has been tapped, and the first item is selected.

Why do I get this warning? How can I call `buttonTapped` properly here?

Comment: What type is `self.horizMenu`?  If it's not a class that responds to `buttonTapped:`, you'll get that warning.  You don't need that typecast to `id`, either.

Comment: self.horizMenu is a MKHorizMenu...

Comment: Ok. But `MKHorizMenu` doesn't have an instance method called `buttonTapped` (at least in the header, which is all the rest of your code has to go on for its information).  Are you sure you're supposed to call that method directly?

Comment: Where the `buttonTapped` method is expected to be? HorizMenu.h does not declare it; neither does its superclass.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - it's in the implementation file.  I'm not familiar with this class myself, but it seems like the OP might be using it differently than the author intended?

Comment: That's what I don't understand - the buttonTapped is in the .m, but not in the header. You'll notice in another part of the class, he uses it solely as `@selector(buttonTapped:)`

Comment: @CarlNorum it appears that I am in fact trying to use this differently myself. I guess what I'm asking is how can* I call it directly?

Comment: It will work the way you have it now - you'll just get that warning.  If you want to stop the warning, just add a forward declaration of that method to the `MKHorizMenu.h` header.

Comment: @CarlNorum I just did that and it worked. I swear I tried that earlier and it didn't work. Perhaps I need a break :). If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the warning by adding the method declaration for `buttonTapped:` to the header file for the class.